# How to merge few lines with filtering some text

Tags: python, python-2.7, parsing, merge

I have a text file with the following format.

The first line includes "USERID"=12345678 and the other lines include the user groups for each application:
For example:

User with user T-number T12345 has WRITE access to the APP1 and APP2 and READ-ONLY access to APP1.

T-Number is just some other kind of ID.

00001, 00002 and so on are sequence numbers and can be ignored.

```
T12345;;USERID;00001;12345678;
T12345;APPLICATION;WRITE;00001;APP1
T12345;APPLICATION;WRITE;00002;APP2
T12345;APPLICATION;READ-ONLY;00001;APP1
```

I need to do some filtering and merge the line containing USERID with all the lines having user groups, matching t-number with userid (T12345 = 12345678)

So the output should look like this.

```
12345678;APPLICATION;WRITE;APP1
12345678;APPLICATION;WRITE;APP2
12345678;APPLICATION;READ-ONLY;APP1
```

Should I use csv python module to accomplish this?

Comment: Your file format is not clear. What is a "user T-number"? Is it another kind of ID? What is the significance of the numbers `00001` and `00002`?

Comment: t-number is just some other kind of ID. 00001 and 00002 are just some sequential numbers for each type of user group (00003, 00004 and so on)

Comment: So the those numbers can be ignored in the parsing of the file, or do they have some significance in the parsing? (I note that two different numbers are used for `USERID 12345678`.

Comment: they can be ignored, apologies if I wasn't clear enough

Comment: It seems like a good idea to use the csv module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not so sure if you should use the `csv` module here - it has mixed data, possibly more than just users and user group rights? In the case of a user declaration, you only need to retrieve its group and id, while for the application rights you need to extract the group, app name and right. The more differing data you have, the more issues you will encounter - with manual parsing of the data you are always able to just `continue` when you met certain criterias.

So far i must say you are better off with a manual, line-by-line parsing of the lines, structure it into something meaningful, then output the data. For instance

```
from StringIO import StringIO
from pprint import pprint

feed = """T12345;;USERID;00001;12345678;
T12345;;USERID;00001;2345678;
T12345;;USERID;00002;345678;
T12345;;USERID;00002;45678;
T12345;APPLICATION;WRITE;00001;APP1
T12345;APPLICATION;WRITE;00002;APP2
T12345;APPLICATION;READ-ONLY;00001;APP1
T12345;APPLICATION;WRITE;00002;APP1
T12345;APPLICATION;WRITE;00002;APP2"""

buf = StringIO(feed)

groups = {}

# Read all data into a dict of dicts
for line in buf:
  values = line.strip().split(";")
  if values[3] not in groups:
    groups[values[3]] = {"users": [], "apps": {}}
  if values[2] == "USERID":
    groups[values[3]]['users'].append(values[4])
    continue
  if values[1] == "APPLICATION":
    if values[4] not in groups[values[3]]["apps"]:
      groups[values[3]]["apps"][values[4]] = []
    groups[values[3]]["apps"][values[4]].append(values[2])

print("Structured data with group as root")
pprint(groups)

print("Output data")
for group_id, group in groups.iteritems():
  # Order by user, app
  for user in group["users"]:
    for app_name, rights in group["apps"].iteritems():
      for right in rights:
        print(";".join([user, "APPLICATION", right, app_name]))
```

[Online demo here](https://repl.it/repls/DecimalMuffledCrash)

Comment: thanks a lot! it appears I will really do the manual parsing as there is no much use in applying csv module for my specific needs

Answer (score 1):

I do not see any advantage in using the `csv` module for reading and parsing the input text file. The number of fields varies: 6 fields in the USERID line, with 2 of them empty, but 5 non-empty fields in the other lines. The fields look very simple, so there is no need for `csv`'s handling of the separator character hidden away in quotes and the like. There is no header line as in a csv file, but rather many headers sprinkled in among the data lines.

A simple routine that reads each line, splits each on the semicolon character, and parses the line, and combines related lines would suffice.

The output file is another matter. The lines have the same format, with the same number of fields. So creating that output may be a good use for csv. However, the format is so simple that the file could also be created without `csv`.